# flask-sqlalchemy ошибка foreignkey

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

#### models.py

```
class Teacher(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teachers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    schedules = db.relationship('Schedule', backref='teacher')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Teacher {}>'.format(self.name)

class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    schedules = db.relationship('Schedule', backref='group')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Group {}>'.format(self.name)

class Schedule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'schedule'
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
    teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teacher.id'))
    weekday = db.Column(db.Integer)
    lesson_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    time_start = db.Column(db.String)
    time_end = db.Column(db.String)
    time = db.Column(db.Integer)
    week = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date = db.Column(db.String)
    auditory_name = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Schedule g:{} l:{} t:{} >'.format(self.group_id, self.lesson_name, self.teacher_id )
```

Ошибка:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'schedule.group_id' could not find table 'group' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Group.id))
teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Teacher.id))
```